# Compare 2 nested dicts and show differences

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, compare

I have simple issue, but I cannot cope with that.
I have 2 nested dictionaries:

```
slownikAG = {1: {1: 2, 2: 'DU', 3: 1614519},
             2: {1: 1, 2: 'D1', 3: 45770912},
             3: {1: 1, 2: 'D1', 3: 45771661},
             4: {1: 1, 2: 'D1', 3: 45771789}}

slownikAE = {1: {1: '45771661', 2: '5500007672', 3: 'RM'},
             2: {1: '45771789', 2: '5500007673', 3: 'RM'},
             3: {1: '45771790', 2: '5500007674', 3: 'RM'}}
```

I need compare if in `slownikAG` we have key no "3" e.g.:
    check if in `slownikAE` is "1614519" - **No**
    check if in `slownikAE` is "45771661" - **Yes - put it to new dictionary**
    check if in `slownikAE` is "45771789" - **Yes - put it to new dictionary**

Output:

```
newwdictionary = {1: {1: '45771661', 2: '5500007672', 3: 'RM'},
                  2: {1: '45771789', 2: '5500007673', 3: 'RM'}}
```

I've tried many times with my code but i have big struggle with comparing those two dictionaries:

```
for male in slownikAG:
    dane = slownikAG[male]
    i = 1
    while i < zakladka2.max_row-1:
        if str(dane[3]) in slownikAE[i][1]:
            print("Exists")
            print(str(dane[3])+" : "+str(slownikAE[i]))
        else:
            print("Missing "+str(dane[3]))
        i += 1
```

Comment: What is `zakladka2.max_row`? In one place you talk about creating a new dictionary, but your compare code just prints things—so what exactly is it that you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
slownikAE = {1: {1: '45771661', 2: '5500007672', 3: 'RM'}, 2: {1: '45771789', 2: '5500007673', 3: 'RM'}, 3: {1: '45771790', 2: '5500007674', 3: 'RM'}}
vals = [1614519, 45771661, 45771789]
newdictionary = {a:b for a, b in slownikAE.items() if any(str(c) in b.values() for c in vals)}
```

Output:

```
{1: {1: '45771661', 2: '5500007672', 3: 'RM'}, 2: {1: '45771789', 2: '5500007673', 3: 'RM'}}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesnt works - it returns empty "final_dict" dictionary. And I cannot change layout of "slownikAG" and "slownikAE" - because its connected with Excel file - I've put data from Excel to dictionaries and I want avoid to change structure of dictionaries.

Comment: @Kris what do you mean? What is the error or issue?